# Axioms for equality

Tags: first-order-logic, relations, axioms

For first order logic without equality, what are the exact axioms we give to define the relation of equality ?

I can't find the exact axioms even in Wikipedia... Any reference to any article or a list of the exact axioms would do ...

Comment: See [Equality and its axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) and see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992776/equality-and-its-axioms).

Comment: If we want to formulate e.g. first-order arithmetic using as underlying logic predicate calculus **without** equality, we have to start with at least $a =b \to (a=c \to b =c)$ that allows us to prove the key properties of equality: $a=a$, $a = b \to b = a$ and $a = b \to ( b = c \to a = c )$ and then we have to prove the substitution property for the three dunction symbols: $s, +, \times$. See e.g. Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics (1952)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Metamathematics/jTUv0AEACAA), Ch.VIII Formal Number Theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA from the post you linked in the comment, it's the 2nd and 3rd axiom I have difficulty understanding,  since the symmetric and transitive property for equality is defined with x=y as a premise itself... how to actually prove if a given x is actually equal to a given y....  I admit this sounds naive, but I am really having a hard time understanding it, maybe I am making a very silly mistake in understanding it...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA given the above doubt, I am facing a dilemma where to me it looks like equality isn't even definable or axiomatizable in first order logic... how to actually show or under what axioms x = y , unless we actually know what x and y are we shouldn't be able to give a general axiom or proof of x = y....

Comment: "it looks like equality isn't even definable or axiomatizable in first order logic" Why? the axioms listed in Wiki's entry **are** the axioms forequality.